# How to add a border to a label in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey

I've made a simple `Hello World!` app in the [DelphiFMX GUI Library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python). "Hello World!" is shown on a `Label` on the `Form` as can be seen below with my code and screenshot:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "ScreenCenter"

        self.myLabel = Label(self)
        self.myLabel.Parent = self
        self.myLabel.Text = "Hello World!"
        self.myLabel.Align = "Client"
        self.myLabel.StyledSettings = ""
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.Font.Size = 85
        self.myLabel.TextSettings.HorzAlign = "Center"


Application.Initialize()
Application.Title = "My Application"
Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
Application.MainForm.Show()
Application.Run()
Application.MainForm.Destroy()
```

[image: Python GUI Hello World App]

Is there a way to add a border around the `Label`? How would one do this?

I tried doing things like the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
self.myLabel.Stroke.Kind = "Solid"
self.myLabel.Stroke.Color = "Black"
self.myLabel.Stroke.Thickness = 1
```

Is it possible to add a border around a `Label`?, if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Label` component doesn't have a Border property by default, but there is a way. The easiest way to give a `Border` to a `Label` isn't to actually give a border to it, but rather to make a `Rectangle` and then put the `Label` into the `Rectangle`:

```
self.myRectangle = Rectangle(self)
self.myRectangle.Parent = self
self.myRectangle.Align = "Center"
self.myRectangle.Width = 525
self.myRectangle.Height = 150
self.myRectangle.Fill.Color = "$0"

self.myLabel = Label(self)
self.myLabel.Parent = self.myRectangle
self.myLabel.Text = "Hello World!"
self.myLabel.Align = "Client"
self.myLabel.StyledSettings = ""
self.myLabel.TextSettings.Font.Size = 85
self.myLabel.TextSettings.HorzAlign = "Center"
```

[image: Python Hello World GUI App]

The `Rectangle` component has a border by default and you can give it a transparent background by doing `self.myRectangle.Fill.Color = "$0"`. You can also adjust the `Color` and `Thickness` of the Border with the following code:

```
self.myRectangle.Stroke.Color = "$FFFF0000"
self.myRectangle.Stroke.Thickness = 15
```

[image: Python GUI App with Hello World Label]